# drupal theme execution flow

Tags: drupal, themes

I am beginner to drupal and doesn't know more about it I am amazing about drupal theme works. And I would like know drupal theme's flow of execution. If i open theme folder..., there is a file like page.tpl, template.tpl,node.tpl and more... In which order the drupal reads all those theming file...

Answer (score 2):

There is no easy answer, it really depends.

The thing with Drupal's theming system, is that it is very flexible, which means, that under certain situations you can make it use other templates, than the default.

The only thing you usually can be sure of, is that the `page.tpl.php` is used, it defines the main structure of the page. It usually defines different regions where you can put dynamic content. This content can be generated by a combination of templates and theme functions.

If you want to understand how this all works, you could try to read the [theme guide](http://drupal.org/documentation/theme), or for a more hands on approach, install the [Theme developer module](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) to inspect the different elements of a drupal page.

Answer (score 0):

Nick Lewis, as always, has a well written piece about the theming internals [here](http://www.nicklewis.org/node/850), [here](http://www.nicklewis.org/drupal-hackers-cookbook/theming/hook_theme-and-template-files), and [here](http://www.nicklewis.org/node/909).  Not one of them gives you the complete overview, but the three of them together creates synergistic drupal awesomeness.